# jQuery target specific section of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use .replace() to replace a specific part of a URL but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Specifically, I'm taking a string that looks like this:

```
'param1=www.DOMAIN.NAME&param2=NUM1&param3=true&param4=25'
```

I'd like to change param2 at my own discretion using jquery.

Currently I just use `.replace('NUM1', newParam);` but as you can see once `'NUM1'` changes to the new parameter that the varaible `newParam` gives it, I can't then change it again as it will no long find `'NUM1'`.

Comment: In that case you can code `replace(newParam, anotherNewParam)`, but it's very fragile, you should target the `param2` and change it's value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Rip the values out of the string and create a new string. `$.param({param1: param1, param2: "myNewValue", param3: param3, param4:param4});`

Comment: How about this regex `.replace('(param2=)[^&]+','$1'+newParam);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know all the other aspects of the string, you could do a quick hack and concatenate the string:

```
str = 'param1=www.DOMAIN.NAME&amp;param2=' + NUM1 + '&amp;param3=true&amp;param4=25'
```

Not elegant, but it'd work.

Alternatively if that string is variable but the NUM1 is always there, you could split('NUM1'), then join(newParam)

e.g.,

```
str = 'param1=www.DOMAIN.NAME&amp;param2=NUM1&amp;param3=true&amp;param4=25'
str.split('NUM1').join(newParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would look into a jQuery plugin for handling query strings. Surely this will always be a querystring-like string. A little searching [turned up this](http://plugins.jquery.com/query-object/), but these kinds of plugins have been around a long time and you're likely to find one that precisely suits your needs.